# add a DATE with a NUMBER and to obtain a DATE in R

Tags: r, function, date, numbers, sum

I have a data frame "Invoice" which look like this:

```
Invoice_ID    Invoice_DATE   Nr_of_days_until_deadline
  101           1/20/2017         7
  102           1/25/2017         4
  103           1/29/2017         5
  104           2/01/2017         4
  105           2/05/2017         3
```

I have to populate the  data frame Deadline_Invoces by writing  R modules   for determining the deadline DATE   for each    invoice,    where deadline_DATE =   Invoice_DATE    +   Nr_of_days_until_deadline.

Thus I have to obtain data frame Deadline_Invoces:

```
    Invoice_ID  Invoice_DATE    Deadline_DATE
```

How should I sum DATE with a NUMBER and to obtain a DATE?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Have a look at the `lubridate` package, it should make it easy.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have your date column formatted as a date...then make a new column, call it `Deadline` or something like that. From there: `Invoice$Deadline <- as.Date(Invoice$Invoice_DATE) + Invoice$Nr_of_days_until_deadline`

Check out the `lubridate` package in R

Comment: Why recommend lubridate when you just solved it easily in base R?

Comment: I was thinking that she may want to do additional tasks with dates that are not so easily solved with base.